# Civisualize not showing default visualization to contribute dashlet other dashlets working fine

Tags: civicrm-home, civisualize

Civisualize not showing default chat view in donation dashlet even data is there , wordpress 6.3.1 ,civicrm 5.65 and ubuntu 20, its works fine in ubuntu 18, ubuntu22 also have the same problem,how to solve this
[image]